# Sudden high email bounce rates when using new email template

Tags: email, html-email, spam, email-bounces

We have been using iContact for Salesforce to send our company's mass emails for a couple years.  We typically have low bounce rates (1-2%) and are consistently sending large numbers of emails (30,000 - 40,000 total sends per month, spread across 10-20 different emails).

Earlier this year, we launched a new product (The Outcomes Survey), and I created a new HTML email template for it with unique branding for the new product. Every time we send an email with this new template, the bounce rates are in excess of 15% (even though it's sent to the same group of contacts we send our typical emails to, and comes from the same email address).

When I pull a bounce report, most of the diagnostic codes are: "spam-related (554 rejected due to spam content)"

I have run the email template itself through several online spam tests, and it comes out clean. As far as I am able to tell, there's nothing in inherently wrong with the email.  You can see a [sample email here](http://www.csoresearch.com/email/sent/2014-08-14_webinar_8-21.html).

When we send emails using our original company branding and template, our bounce rates are low. Any email sent with The Outcomes Survey branding, bounce rates jump up again.

I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by recreating the email from another template that has worked in the past. So, I guess there was some code in the original HTML email template that was causing problems, although I wish I knew what it was!